# Mac OS X partition doesn't boot after enabling Bitlocker

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, macbook-pro, boot-camp, bitlocker

I have dualboot MacBook Pro. After enabling Bitlocker in Windows 10 I am not able to boot my OS X partition. Only recovery partition is bootable. I am able to open my OS partition from Windows and see files. How can I fix it?

Here is my partitions in Disk Manager:

[image]

D: is the Mac OS X partition.

UPDATE:

I have deleted Bitlocker partition using Diskpart. But now my Mac OS X recovery partition also doesn't show up in boot menu. My updated partitions lokk like this:

[image]

Mac partitions is still there but they are not showing up when I press option button on Mac starts.

Comment: What model MacBook Pro is it?  What year?

Comment: 2015 MacBook Pro

Comment: It has a ssd drive.

Comment: Your partitions are likely screwed up by Bitlocker.  Please open Disk Management in Windows and paste a screenshot of your partition layout into your question.

Comment: @wessayead i have added my partition info.

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshots, you should be able to just change your startup disk.  Try holding down the <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keys to boot directly to your Recovery partition.  Then choose Startup Disk from the Apple menu.

If you can't get into recovery mode, try holding down <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to boot to Internet Recovery.

Full-disk encryption -- whether it's Mac's FileVault2, or Windows' BitLocker -- always requires an unencrypted support partition in order to boot an encrypted operating system.  This is why OS X creates the recovery partition on a Mac, and Windows creates a System Reserved partition on a PC.  In both OS X and Windows, even though your OS drive "looks" like the system drive, the computer does not actually boot from it.  It boots from the support partition, which then loads the OS off whatever drive it's installed on.

In your case, you either used Boot Camp to install Windows, or you created a partition for it in Disk Utility.  Either way, Windows did not have an extra partition to work with when you installed it, so the OS partition was also the boot partition.

When you enabled Bitlocker, it had to create this extra support partition on-the-fly.  It shrank your Windows partition (C: drive) and created that extra 346MB partition you see in your screenshot.  When it did this, it changed your boot device, and this is why you can no longer boot into OS X.

To boot into OS X, shut down your Mac and hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key while turning it back on.  This should bring up the Mac's firmware boot menu and you should be able to see and select your OS X partition there.

Once you're in, you'll want to use the Startup Disk control panel to set your Mac back to the default.

Also note, you will not be able to see your Windows partition when booted into OS X.  Apple does not support Bitlocker (just as Microsoft doesn't support FileVault), so the "Windows" partition you see in Finder is the support partition Windows created, not the OS volume itself.

Comment: I have disabled Bitlocker and deleted it's partition using Diskpart. Now I am able boot Windows but this time my Mac OS X recovery partitipn is also lost :)

Comment: OS X can boot fine without the recovery partition, just as Windows can function without its support partition.  You will not be able to enable FileVault, however.  Unlike Windows, Apple does not provide any tools to recreate the recovery partition if it is lost.

Comment: From the updated screenshot it looks like all your partitions are still there.  Try booting your Mac to recovery mode by holding down Command+R while turning it on.  You should be able to use Startup Disk (from the Apple menu) to select your Mac partition and reboot.  You also might want to use Disk Utility to do First Aid on the disk.

Comment: If Command+R doesn't work, try Command+Option+R.  That will boot you to Internet Recovery -- useful for situations where your recovery partition is borked (although it doesn't appear that way from your screenshots).

Comment: My partition table was corrupted and I have tried to fix it but failed. So I have formatted my Mac.